# Message.js is throwing error "Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to restructure my message.js to work smoother and allow for aliases in my commands. I copied literally almost all the code letter for letter from a tutorial and just changed a few things to fit my bot as I wasn't quite sure the best way of doing so. Now it's not only reacting to commands its reacting to literally every message sent and throws the error in the title. I'm not sure why content isn't defined, if someone could help that'd be great.

Here is my message.js (I've removed database stuff that was previously there as it just congests the code block and has nothing to do with the issue)

```js
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
const config = require('../config.json');

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    //command handler start

    let prefix = config.prefix;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    const command = client.commands.get(cmd)  || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
   
    if(!command) return message.channel.send(":x: This is not a valid command");

    command.execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData);
}
```

For reference, here is the code that used to be in this document that worked.

```
module.exports = (client, message) => {
    
    if (message.author.bot) return;
  
    
    if (message.content.indexOf(client.config.prefix) !== 0) return;
  
    
    const args = message.content.slice(client.config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command);
  
    
    if (!cmd) return;
  
    
    cmd.run(client, message, args);
};
```

All I added was a prefix check using,

```
let prefix = config.prefix;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

and check for aliases using

```
const command = client.commands.get(cmd)  || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It's not complaining that the ```content``` is undefined.  It's complaining (I believe) ```message``` is undefined as that's the only object that's referenced with the content attribute/property.   Does the error specify any particular line?

Comment: `message` is undefined. Please show the code where you execute this function.

Comment: @ewong Yes its at line 8 where it checks if the message starts with the prefix which is also the first time message.content is used,

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

Comment: How is `message` passed to the module?

Comment: @DarylGill Would that not be the top where its | module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {

Comment: This is your message event? as that is only one argument `module.exports = async (message)` Unless you're binding another few params to the event in which case, show the code?

Comment: @DarylGill Yea all this is doing is checking for commands, and then at the bottom uses command.execute to execute whatever is in that command.js like help.js I assumed, like how it previously worked that since its exporting message from discord.js src that it would just read message.content as that

Comment: Please show where you're executing the function exported by this file.

Comment: @Lioness100 like in the commands?

Comment: I would recommend referring to the manual for the client events. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message, You will see one argument is passed. For the top example to be working as your `client.on('message')` event. You will be calling it from somewhere else and binding to beable to use `discord` and `client` inside this event. Where are you doing that?

Comment: Looking back at your old code, assuming you changed nothing about how it was called, your problem is that you added the `Discord` variable from nowhere but didn't actually supply it. Right now `Discord` is `client`, `client` is `message`, and `message` is nothing.

Comment: @Lioness100 ok, how would I fix that. I need Discord in there otherwise commands that use Discord for things like embeds will no longer work. I guess I am under knowledge about calling variables. Note: Discord is in my main.js as Discord = require("discord.js") so it is a thing inside the bot

Comment: The tutorial you are going through or a previous tutorial would have went over event/command handlers, go back over them

Comment: @DarylGill I did, many times. The only difference I can see is that they have their event handler in its own folder where I have mine in my main.js (index.js) but it seemingly is/does the exact same things

Comment: So, compare your event handler as is against the event module you are attempting to run & You will notice a difference

Comment: @DarylGill I did what I was dreading and just completely redid my command and event handler and reworked most of my command executions and calls and it worked. Thanks for forcing me lmao

Comment: @Saoul I'm gald you fixed it. The rule of thumb is to **never** use code you don't understand, or you'll be forced into these situations.